# Will Baidu spider understand an infinite scrolling page?

Tags: seo, javascript, baidu, infinite-scroll

My team is looking at implementing an infinite scrolling page while maintaining good SEO. We're following Google's advice for infinite scrolling SEO from this article:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/infinite-scroll-search-friendly.html

and this example:
http://scrollsample.appspot.com/items?page=4

It looks entirely possible to make endless pagination SEO-friendly so long as each of your pages is separately addressable using `rel="next"`/`"prev"` and the HTML5 history API is used to alert the DOM when a new page is loaded.

The problem is, Chinese search engines are important to us too. And there is very little information about them in English. So the question I have is: Is Baidu's crawler (Baiduspider) smart enough to understand endless JavaScript pagination, in the same way Google's bot apparently can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, according to [this](http://www.baiduguide.com/baidu-seo-guide/baiduspider-crawl-technology/), Baidoo doesn't read Javascripts, Ajax etc. But the approach in example code by John Mueller lets address every page through own urls and, beside of it, through the pagination links on the bottom of every page and `rel="prev/next"` in the head.

So, the site using infinite scrolling/pagination as in example will look for Baidoo as a site without infinite scrolling, but with a *normal*, clickable pagination. With clickable `a href` pagination links and `rel="prev/next"` the Baidoo crawler will be able to crawl the whole site properly.

You can test it by your own through setting your browser javascript off and trying to browse through the site.

Comment: Cheers mate. Really solid advice